# Space check previous page and insert rows there Excel

Tags: vba, excel, function

I have block of text in (A795:O830). It is separated from other pages by Page Break and is always the last page of printed (xls, pdf) document. Sometimes there are a lot of free space on first pages and (A795:O830) could have fitted there. Now it is done by Page Break and is not changeble. In my situation 66 rows can fit on one page.

Is there any macro that can automatically check if there is enough empty space on previous page to fit (A795:O830) and insert it there?

Here is my current macro:

```
Sub Remove_color()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set myRange = Range("A24:O785")
        For Each cell In myRange
        myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Next
End Sub
Sub Hide_empty_cells()
    Set rr = Range("A24:N832")
    For Each cell In rr
    cell.Select
        If cell.HasFormula = True And cell.Value = "" And cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next cell
End Sub
Sub Save_excel()
    Dim iFileName$, iRow&, iCol&, iCell As Range, iArr
    iFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\New_folder_" & [D5] & "_" & ".xls"
    iArr = Array(1, 3, 4): iCol = UBound(iArr) + 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
         .Buttons.Delete '.Shapes("Button 1").Delete
         .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value
         .SaveAs iFileName, xlExcel8: .Parent.Close
    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub Save_pdf()
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\New_folder_\" & [D5] & "_" & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=No, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
Sub doitallplease()
Call Remove_color
Call Hide_empty_cells
Call Save_excel
Call Save_pdf
End Sub
```